# Display/Hide content with fading

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following `jQuery` code which you can also find in the `JSfiddle`[here](http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/32/):

```js
/* Code for buttons individually */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel_button").on('click', function() {
    $(".panel").hide();
    var targetPanel = $(this).attr('data-target');
     $(targetPanel).show();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});


/* Code for previous and next buttons */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $(".next_button").click(function(){
        if ($(".panel:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".panel:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".panel:visible").hide();
            $(".panel:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(".prev_button").click(function(){
        if ($(".panel:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".panel:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".panel:visible").hide();
            $(".panel:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel_button, .prev_button, .next_button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

#panel1, #panel2, #panel3 {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents">

  <div id="panel1" class="panel">
    <div class="content_01a">Here goes content1a</div>
    <div class="content_01b">Here goes content1b</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel2" class="panel">
    <div class="content_02a">Here goes content2a</div>
    <div class="content_02b">Here goes content2b</div>
    <div class="content_02c">Here goes content2c</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel3" class="panel">
    <div class="content_03a">Here goes content3a</div>
    <div class="content_03b">Here goes content3b</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="buttons">
  
  <div class="prev_button"> PREVIOUS </div>

  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel1"> Button_01 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel2"> Button_02 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel3"> Button_03 </div>
  
  <div class="next_button"> NEXT </div>
  
</div>
```

As you can see in the code above I want to show/hide `contents` when a `button` is clicked. 
 All this works fine so far.

---

Now I want to add a `fading` animation to the show/hide of the contents. Therefore, I tried to change the `.hide` to `.fadeOut` and the `.show` to `.fadeIn` as you can see in the JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/55/) but unfortunatley this animation does not really run smoothly. 
 
The contents first appear below the previous content and once the previous content is fully faded out they jump to their final position.

Do you know what I have to change in my code to avoid this jumping?

Comment: you would need to position one of the divs absolutely whilst the animation happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#panel1, #panel2, #panel3 {
  position: absolute; // <-- add this line
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

Fix: http://jsfiddle.net/Dezain/ydgx3szt/

Comment: Thanks. Exactly, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Asper @Thielicious you need to add position absolute for those panel to keep all of those in the same position so that they aren't blink and you can add call back function to show desire panel after fadeout all panel expect which one you want to show.

```
  $(".panel_button").on('click', function() {
      var id=$(this).data('target');
      $(".panel:not('"+id+"')").fadeOut('slow',function(){
       $(id).fadeIn('slow');
      })
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/55/

Answer (score 0):

You can add duration to your [fade in](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [fade out](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).
I have addded a lil bit duration for you.

```js
  

  /* Code for buttons individually */
    /* Code for buttons individually */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel_button").on('click', function() {
    $(".panel").fadeOut(1000);
    var targetPanel = $(this).attr('data-target');
     $(targetPanel).fadeIn(1000);
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});


/* Code for previous and next buttons */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $(".next_button").click(function(){
        if ($(".panel:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".panel:visible").next().fadeIn(1000).prev().fadeOut(1000);
        else {
            $(".panel:visible").fadeOut(1000);
            $(".panel:first").fadeIn(1000);
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(".prev_button").click(function(){
        if ($(".panel:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".panel:visible").prev().fadeIn(1000).next().fadeOut(1000);
        else {
            $(".panel:visible").fadeOut(1000);
            $(".panel:last").fadeIn(1000);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel_button, .prev_button, .next_button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

#panel1, #panel2, #panel3 {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents">

  <div id="panel1" class="panel">
    <div class="content_01a">Here goes content1a</div>
    <div class="content_01b">Here goes content1b</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel2" class="panel">
    <div class="content_02a">Here goes content2a</div>
    <div class="content_02b">Here goes content2b</div>
    <div class="content_02c">Here goes content2c</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel3" class="panel">
    <div class="content_03a">Here goes content3a</div>
    <div class="content_03b">Here goes content3b</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="buttons">
  
  <div class="prev_button"> PREVIOUS </div>

  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel1"> Button_01 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel2"> Button_02 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel3"> Button_03 </div>
  
  <div class="next_button"> NEXT </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi better to add some duration to fadeIn or fadeOut to make it more animated
also add css

```
 #panel1, #panel2, #panel3 {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/koanfw15/83/) please take a look with new animation.